# Fibonacci sequence return

Tags: php, fibonacci

I'm playing with a Fibonacci sequence using PHP. I understand the concept of recursive functions, but I don't understand what's going on here.

Code:

```
function fs($n) {
    if ($n < 1) {
       return 1;
    } // if

    echo " n is " . $n . "<br>"; 
    echo fs($n - 1) + fs($n - 2) . " when n is " . $n . "<br>";
} // function

echo fs(3);
```

And here is the return:

```
n is 3
n is 2
n is 1
2 when n is 1
1 when n is 2
n is 1
2 when n is 1
0 when n is 3
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? What you have is a function that calculates the Fibonacci number. Do you not understand the Fibonacci sequence, or do you not understand the output?

Comment: I understand the Fibonacci but don't understand the output.  "n is 3", then "n is 2" then "n is 1" - why is the next output "2 when n is 1"?  It's the order of code execution I don't understand.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `function`, if the input is smaller than 1 will return 1. Otherwise it will print the value of the input and call the function recursively for lower values. Since for -1 it will return 1, you will get incorrect values. Let's call it with 1. It will call it for 0 and -1, returning 1 for each and adding them, resulting in 2, which is incorrect. You need to implement it in a different way:

```
    function fs($n){

    if ($n<=1) {
        return 1;
    }
    echo fs($n-1)+fs($n-2) ." when n is ".$n. "<br>";   

   } //function

   fs(3);
```

This will fix the issue.